# NoSuchMethodError when using Apache Commons Math3 (Java)

Tags: java, apache, nosuchmethoderror

```
final WeightedObservedPoints obs = new WeightedObservedPoints();
for(int i = 0; i < pointList.size() - 1; i++) {
    obs.add(i, getDistance(pointList.get(i), pointList.get(i + 1)));
    obs.add(0,0);
    obs.add(1,1);
    obs.add(2,2);
    obs.add(3,3);
}

// Instantiate a third-degree polynomial fitter.
final PolynomialCurveFitter fitter = PolynomialCurveFitter.create(3);

// Retrieve fitted parameters (coefficients of the polynomial function).
final double[] coeff = fitter.fit(obs.toList());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(coeff));
```

I'm using Apache Commons Math3 to fit a polynomial and get the following error. Any thoughts?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.math3.util.Pair.getFirst()Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.leastsquares.LeastSquaresFactory$LocalLeastSquaresProblem.evaluate(LeastSquaresFactory.java:431)
at org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.leastsquares.LeastSquaresAdapter.evaluate(LeastSquaresAdapter.java:60)
at org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.leastsquares.LeastSquaresFactory$1.evaluate(LeastSquaresFactory.java:197)
at org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.leastsquares.LevenbergMarquardtOptimizer.optimize(LevenbergMarquardtOptimizer.java:328)
at org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.AbstractCurveFitter.fit(AbstractCurveFitter.java:63)
```

Comment: You compiled with a different version than you ran with.

Comment: Yeah I thought so but I'm not sure how to resolve it. All I did was add external JAR to my build path in eclipse, how can it be using different versions when compiling and running?

Comment: Do you run from inside eclipse, or from some other place like a command line?

Comment: That suggests that you have two copies of the jar added to your build path(s), and you need to eliminate the older one.

Comment: There were actually conflicting JAR names, nice one